# How can i get email history from iphone device..?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, history

friends

I want to access email history from my iphone & also want notification when new mail receive.

- Provide me source code snippet if possible.

Thanks,

Comment: what have you tried already? people will generally not give you code but will help fix the code you have already written if it doesnt work as expected

Answer (score 2):

In short: It is not possible with any of the documented APIs

Answer (score 1):

Most of us have this question in our mind, “Can iPhones get viruses from Email?”. iPhones are highly secure, which is a known fact. Yet, there are certain possibilities where viruses can enter into the device through apps or email. Everyone’s idea of the iPhone is that it is entirely immune to malware (malicious attacks). Even iPhones get malwares when they are jailbroken. Protect your iPhone from other threats by taking sensible precautions.

For instance, your device might encounter phishing attacks more than iOS malware. Be careful while opening an email on your iPhone. Avoid opening junk mails, which could result in letting the virus into your iPhone. Do not open the email links that look suspicious. Even if you have opened some spam email on your mobile mistakenly, do not click any of the links given inside it. Lets quickly see things that indicate the presence of viruses in the iPhone.

These are the possible signs that indicate whether your iPhone is infected with malware, a virus or some other threat.

1. Encounter system warning frequently.
2. Advertisements popping-up often
3. Apps crashing
4. Incline in the mobile data usage

If you encounter these issues, then it might indicate the presence of a bug that requires to be deleted or updated. Sometimes, your phone might run out of memory space or the battery needs replacement. All these indicate the presence of a virus.